# PHPfox Admincp url

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpfox

I need help regarding admin panel login page.

I have downloaded fresh copy of phpfox

now when I am going for url:

http://localhost/php...php?do=/admincp

it takes me to some login page like attached in image 1

and after that it takes me to another login page as attached in image 2

so why I need to login twice here for admincp?

and what if I want direct (image 2) page, how to jump direct on that page? because URL is the same

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not access admin directly. You have to login from frontend so you can login with admin login page.

```
admin login check frontend session first then processed further
```

Comment: thanks friends, atleast got the answer for phpfox :)

Comment: then how to logout from admin?

Comment: @Er.KT you can't logout from admin.